# String split in c# returning an empty array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to split a string in C# that shows time, for example "`00:00`" into an array that becomes "`00`" and "`00`" by splitting it at the '`:`' part of the string. I keep getting "`System.String[]`" though.

Why am I getting an empty string array?

```
string time = "00:00";

Console.WriteLine(time.Split(':'));
```

Comment: Who knows? Put your code into the question...

Comment: Where are you getting `System.String[]`? Is it the result of a `.ToString()` by any chance?

Comment: Are you getting an empty string array, or just incorrectly assuming that `array.ToString()` will show you the values?

Comment: My bet is that you do `string[] array = something.Split(':');` and then `Console.WriteLine(array.ToString());` and now you've printed out the type of the array instead of it's values.

Comment: Just added it, my bad

Comment: And the answer is here below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably printing the result directly to your console/view. The string is splitted just fine, but you cannot just print an array. The ToString function of an array will just print the type, which in your case is `System.String[]`.

If you want to print the data you have to join it back to a string or print the parts separately.

```
var splittedString = time.Split(':');

// All parts, glued with a comma
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" , ", splittedString));

// Only the first part
Console.WriteLine(splittedString[0]);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Glad I could help. Considder marking this answer as the solution so other users might find this as well.